# Angular populate components from one place to other

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

I am pretty new to angular, and I am trying to achieve the following situation:
lets say I have a form-control A, that has:

```
    <div class="col-sm-9">
       <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
       <mat-label> Case1 </mat-label>
         <textarea spellcheck="true" matInput placeholder="" formControlName="A" cols="100"
       </mat-form-field>
   </div>

 <div class="col-sm-9">
       <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
       <mat-label> Case2 </mat-label>
         <textarea spellcheck="true" matInput placeholder="" formControlName="A" cols="100"
       </mat-form-field>
   </div>
```

lets say I have other form-control B, that has:

```
<div class = "col-sm-12">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style = "margin-top:10px;" appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>comment #{{i+1}}</mat-label>
    <textarea spellcheck="true" matInput placeholder="" formControlName="B"  cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
     </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

Now, how do I populate the "comment" field with the form A's case1 and case2 values (if they are entered)?

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having different `formControlName` for both inputs, otherwise, whatever value you enter in the first input with `A`, will be reflected for the second input as well since both have the same form control name as `A`.

Since you are using `formControlName`, means you are using the `ReactiveForms` approach, meaning, somewhere in the component's code, you have created the form as a javascript object, either by using `FormBuilder` or `FormControl`, for example:

```js
myForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {} // using FormBuilder

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    A: ['', Validators.required],
    B: [''],
    C: ['']
 });
}
```

So, if you want to populate your input with whatever your input control `A` has in real time, you could do it by using `valueChanges` which returns an `observable`.

**template HTML**

```html
<input formControlName="A" type="text"/>
<input formControlName="B" type="text"/>
```

**component**

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  ...
  this.myForm.get('A').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    this.myForm.get('B').patchValue(value);
  })
}
```

Don't forget to managed the subscription.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ity1zv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi @Andres2142 Thanks for the answer. It really gave me an idea on how to approach this problem. Whatever you said is absolutely correct. I did change the form control names, but here is the catch. My input B is in other html. so can I import my B's form group and control name in the app.ts file and patch the A's value into B?